# How to make a batch file that lets you use cmd after?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

what I'm essentially trying to do is make a batch file (or shortcut if possible) to change to a directory, echo a message, and then let you use the cmd window as if you had opened it up normally after.

Example:

> - The batch file/shortcut opens a cmd prompt in C:\test-folder\
> - Echos "This is your message"
> - Awaits user input for commands

I've tried the following command:

> start cmd /k cd /d C:\test-folder\
>
> echo test

The folder change will work without the echo line, but if I include the echo line, it will not work at all.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

the order of the switches matters. See `start /?` and `cmd /?` for details.

```
start "My window" /d "d:\" cmd /k "echo Hello&echo use me"
```

`"My window"` belongs to `start` and gives the new window a title.

`/d "c:\test-Folder\"` also belongs to `start` and gives the startdirectory

`cmd` is the command to start

`/k` belongs to `cmd` and has to be `cmd`'s (only or) last Switch

`"echo Hello&echo use me"`  is the commandline to execute.

Comment: What you say is true, but the OP's START command is also valid. The START command runs without any options, and launches CMD, which uses a single option /K to run the remainder of the command and remain. The CD command uses the /D option to change both the active drive as well as the active directory.

Comment: that's nearly correct. He could change it to `start cmd /k "cd /d d:\ & echo hello"`. But why wasting a command in the new window, when you can set the directory with it's start?

Comment: Absolutely, I already have that solution in my answer. The reason for my comment is that your answer implies (but does not state) that the OP's command was jumbled, when in fact it was valid. He simply neglected to append the ECHO command to the /K option. There are lots of ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `echo test` is run in the parent window that issues the START command. You want the ECHO to occur in the window that START launches.

One option is to append the ECHO command to the end of the START command, remembering to escape the `&` so that it is included as part of the CMD /K option.

```
start cmd /k cd /d C:\test-folder\ ^& echo test
```

Or you could put quotes around the entire /K option (CMD will remove the quotes before executing the string):

```
start cmd /k "cd /d C:\test-folder\ & echo test"
```

Or you could use Stephan's suggestion to let START set your active directory, so that your CMD /K option only needs to ECHO the message.

```
start /d "C:\test-folder" cmd /k echo test
```

Or you can create a shortcut and edit the properties such that
"Target" = `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k echo test`
and
"Start in" = `c:\test-folder`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a batch file that ends with `cmd /k`, it will run the commands before `cmd /k` and then leave you in a command prompt. This is useful if you're performing enough work that makes a one-liner shortcut hard to write.

To get the behaviour you described, you can create a file called "open_test_folder.cmd" with the following:

```
@echo off
cd C:\test-folder
echo This is your message
cmd /k
```